# Node.js: Automatically Sending Confirmation Emails for Movie Ticket Bookings

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

I'm working on a project where I need to automatically send confirmation emails to customers who book movie tickets through my system. I'm using Node.js and attempting to integrate it with Microsoft Office 365 to send the emails. My system processes approximately 300 ticket bookings per day.

Unfortunately, I'm encountering an error and can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code. I'd appreciate any help or guidance you can provide to resolve this issue. Please find the error message below

```bash
root@localhost:~# node mail.js 
Error sending email: AuthenticationRequiredError: entry.trim is not a function
    at MsalClientSecret.handleError (/root/node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:470:16)
    at MsalClientSecret.doGetToken (/root/node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:2963:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
                                                                                    at async Object.withSpan (/root/node_modules/@azure/core-tracing/dist/index.js:140:28) {
  statusCode: -1,
  code: 'AuthenticationRequiredError',
```

I am sure that `<tenant-id>, <client-id>, <client-secret>` is correct

```
const { Client } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

// Set up Azure AD credentials
const tenantId = 'a59f9b77-8fcc-u44-9a7084dd7b1f';
const clientId = '4e5d95f1-7d78-4a9';
const clientSecret = '97efbe93-7cbfa';
const clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

// Initialize Microsoft Graph client
const client = Client.init({
  authProvider: (done) => {
    clientSecretCredential.getToken({
      scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
    }).then((token) => {
      done(null, token.accessToken);
    }).catch((error) => {
      done(error, null);
    });
  }
});

// Define email message
const emailMessage = {
  toRecipients: [{ emailAddress: { address: 'teeramail@gmail.com' } }],
  subject: 'My new email',
  body: {
    content: 'This is a test email message',
    contentType: 'text'
  },
  isDraft: false
};

// Send email message
client.api('/me/sendMail').post({ message: emailMessage }).then((response) => {
  console.log('Email sent:', response);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error sending email:', error);
});
```

Comment: I call to support of Microsoft they set up less security in Asure then I can sent  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/ndr/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online  they recommend me to read this link